# ae.net.mail retrieve messages from different mailboxes

Tags: c#, email

So, how do i exactly retrieve a message from a mailbox which isnt INBOX? i tried ANY other mailbox possible-

```
public static MailMessage[] LastNMails(ImapClient listenClient, int count)
{
    int endMailBox = listenClient.GetMessageCount() - 1;
    return listenClient.GetMessages(endMailBox - count, endMailBox, false, false);
}


ImapClient listenClient=new ImapClient(my data here.. doesnt matter);
var listMailboxes = listenClient.ListMailboxes(string.Empty, "*");
List<string> working = new List<string>();
foreach (var Mailbox in listMailboxes)
{
    try
    {
        listenClient.SelectMailbox(Mailbox.Name);
        working.Add(Mailbox.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
MailMessage[] mm = null;
foreach (var item in working)
{
    try
    {
        listenClient.SelectMailbox(item);
        mm = LastNMails(listenClient, 1);
        Console.WriteLine(item+" YES");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item+ " FAILED");
    }

}
```

Yet it prints FAILED on any mailbox other than INBOX or [Gmail]/All Mail, any idea why?

Output(if it matters) https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI6fF.png

The error-

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: I am not a Gmail user but I think I vaguely remember their "folders" not actually being folders. They are more like categories. That might explain why "all" works.

Comment: You can't.  The email is associated with the User Login on the PC.  So you can only get access to your login email and not somebody else login.  It is like on the same PC trying to access another users desktop.

Comment: @jdweng but i am able to retrieve mail from INBOX and All Mail, the problem is with other mailboxes.

Comment: That is exactly what I said.